# Во время make пишет no such file or directory

Tags: linux, makefile

Пытаюсь компилировать POCL, а минут через 5 пишет:

`pocl_llvm_api.cc:32:41 fatal error: clang/CodeGen/CodeGenAction.h: No such file or directory`

В файле pocl_llvm_api.cc, в строке 32 написанно:

> #include "clang/CodeGen/CodeGenAction.h:"

Сама библиотека clang находится в /usr/lib/llvm-3.5/include , но не хочется в ручную указовать в каждом файле, их там много. Пробывал скопировть папку clang рядом с файлом Makefile, но приплыли другие проблемы.
Можно ли как то указать на местонахождение библиотеки?

Comment: **Action.h:"** -- это опечатка или так и написано?

Comment: @PinkTux нет, так написанно

Comment: согласно [документации](https://github.com/pocl/pocl/blob/master/doc/sphinx/source/install.rst), конфигурирование производится запуском программы *cmake*. раз конфигурация прошла неудачно, рекомендую её повторить. если не поможет, вероятно, надо явно указать какие-нибудь из приведённых там же опций программы *cmake*. // а к программе *make* ваш вопрос, насколько я понимаю, не имеет **вообще ни малейшего отношения**.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin конфигурация производилось не с помощью cmake, а скриптом ./configure, которое ни каких проблем не выдал. Просто при прямой компиляции скажем командой g++ name.cpp можно прибавить -llib и указать расположение библиотеки, и хочется узнать, как указать место программе make или скрипту ./configure

Comment: Воспользуйтесь подсказкой **./configure --help** там наверника указана опция подключения различных библиотек или напрямую или через общию опцию `LIBS`